# Understanding MFA and MCA with FactoMineR

Tags: r, multivariate-analysis, factor-analysis

I'm working on a project where I have to perform MCA and MFA.
My dataset contains the following [data](https://openpowerlifting.gitlab.io/opl-csv/bulk-csv-docs.html) (for context). Also I created some extra
variables:

- WeightTried* for each lift, that has the absolute value to remove the negative values
- Lifted*? for each lift, that is `Not lifted` if the lift was < 0 and `Lifted` otherwise.

There are several questions that I have regarding those methods:

- What are the `support groups` and the `active groups`? What is the importance of those in MCA and MFA?
- Why we use `cos2` as a metric?
- My explained variance for 2 dimensions is around 22 percent. Is that important in this kind of analysis? As we have more categories, I could think that is not as important as in the PCA.

Thanks

Comment: What is MCA? What is MFA?

Comment: @RichardHardy Multiple correspondence analysis and  Multiple factor analysis

Comment: Is multiple factor analysis different from factor analysis (exploratory or confirmatory)?

Comment: @RichardHardy it is, see http://www.sthda.com/english/articles/31-principal-component-methods-in-r-practical-guide/116-mfa-multiple-factor-analysis-in-r-essentials/#:~:text=Multiple%20factor%20analysis%20(MFA)%20(,or%20qualitative)%20structured%20into%20groups.